# Referring to external function parameter within $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am listening to websocket events with SockJS and want to insert received objects into my `$scope.mails.items` which is an array. I have the below code snippet and my problem is that for some reason I am not able to pass the `message` into my delayed function. I know... I tried to read some explanations about this issue asked repeatedly, but still was not able to figure out why it is not working in this particular case. The reason I need to delay this is that I'd like to make sure it gets applied to my view, it does not otherwise.

```
MyService.receive().then(null, null, function(message) {
          $timeout(function(m) {
              if($scope.mails.items.indexOf(m) == -1) {
                  $scope.mails.items.push(m);
              }
          }, 0, true, message);
    });
```

When debugging it, I can see that the `message` variable has proper value but when it comes to stopping in the middle of my delayed function, `m` is not getting the data, however I would expect `$timeout` to pass it down.

Can you please help?

Comment: can you log `console.log(arguments)` inside `$timeout` function. it maybe not your first argument you expected to be the `m`

Comment: It should work. Have you tried `bind` instead (a more idiomatic JS alternative to custom tricks), like `$timeout(function(m) { ... }.bind(message))`? Btw, there's no reason why `message` cannot be used directly here instead of `m` (as the answer suggests).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `m` is not getting value (explanation welcome), but this works:

```
MyService.receive().then(null, null, function(message) {
          $timeout(function() {
              if($scope.mails.items.indexOf(message) == -1) {
                  $scope.mails.items.push(message);
              }
          }, 0, true, message);
    });
```

Comment: don't even need `message` as argument of `$timeout()` since it is available already in your javascript scope

Comment: Correct, I can remove `message` from after true and it still works. I wonder what was my mistake initially. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

The callback function for $timeout does not take any parameters. That m parameter is always going to be null, just use the message parameter from the outer function.